# Html.Hidden() input element is causing "Changes you made may not be saved." pop-up to appear

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC application that uses a HTML.Hidden() field to keep track of some local variables in JavaScript. However, this field is causing a modal saying:

*"Do you want to leave this site.
Changes you made may not be saved."*

My question is, how can I have this hidden field ignored by the browser so that pop-up will not appear if nothing has been edited?

Comment: That comes from your JS code (`onbeforeunload`), not the field.

Comment: I don't see any code...

Comment: The only bit of code that I initially thought was relevant was the hidden filed with is Html.Hidden("valueName", Math.Min(maxCount, currentCount)).

Comment: Okay I see that function, looks like I need to extract `&valueName=0` and replace it with '&valueName=1'